# C# asynchronous LCD write

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, concurrency

So I'm working on a project that involves a LCD screen that can update 60 times per second. It uses a `BitmapFrame` and I need to copy those pixels to a library that updates the screen. Currently I'm getting about 30-35 FPS which is too low. So I'm trying to use multi-threading but this creates a lot of problems.

The DisplayController already creates a thead to do all the work on like so:

```
public void Start()
{
    _looper = new Thread(Loop);
    _looper.IsBackground = true;
    _looper.Start();
}

private void Loop()
{
    while (_IsRunning)
    {
        renderScreen();
    }
}
```

Which calls the `renderScreen` method that draws all the elements and copies the pixels to the `BitmapFrame`. But this proces takes too long so my FPS drops. My attempt to solve this problem was by creating a `Task` that draws, copies and writes the pixels. But this solution uses a lot of CPU and causes glitchtes on the screen.

```
public void renderScreen()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_object);

        // Push screen to LCD
        BitmapFrame bf = BitmapFrame.Create(screen);
        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(bf, BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality);
        bf.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), pixels, width * 4, 0);

        DisplayWrapper.USBD480_DrawFullScreenBGRA32(ref disp, pixels);

        Monitor.Exit(_object);
    });
}
```

I've been reading a lot about concurrent queues for C# but that's not what I need. And using two threads causes the issue that the compiler says that the variable is owned by another thread.

How can I concurrently render a new bitmap and write that bitmap 60 times per second to the LCD?

Comment: Your Loop method is an infinite loop which creates and starts a task without waiting for it to finish. So it would start like 1000 tasks or threads per second. Of course this slows everything down, even when all of them are waiting at your Monitor lock, because new tasks/thread are continuously created. Remove the Task.Run, and the Monitor lock.

Comment: @ckuri That was my previous version. This caused the application to be too slow, around 30 FPS. That's why I was experimenting with the Task.Run. But you're right about the infite loop creation part that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have two threads (and two only):

1. one that continuously creates the bitmap; and
2. one that continuously takes the most recent bitmap and pushes it to LCD.

---

Here's my naive implementation.

I used a shared array that contains the latest produced image because it keeps number of allocations low. A shared array we can get away with 3 array objects (shared + 2 thread locals).

```
public class Program
{
    public class A
    {
        private readonly object pixelsLock = new object();

        Array shared = ...;

        public void Method2()
        {
            Array myPixels = (...);
            while (true)
            {
                // Prepare image
                BitmapFrame bf = BitmapFrame.Create(screen);
                RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(bf, BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality);
                bf.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), myPixels, width * 4, 0);

                lock (pixelsLock)
                {
                    // Copy the hard work to shared storage
                    Array.Copy(sourceArray: myPixels, destinationArray: shared, length: myPixels.GetUpperBound(0) - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Method1()
        {
            Array myPixels = (...);
            while (true)
            {
                lock (pixelsLock)
                {
                    //Max a local copy
                    Array.Copy(sourceArray: shared, destinationArray: myPixels, length: myPixels.GetUpperBound(0) - 1);
                }
                DisplayWrapper.USBD480_DrawFullScreenBGRA32(ref disp, myPixels);
            }
        }
    }


    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(a.Method1)).Start();
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(a.Method2)).Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your idea of using the pixels als shared memory was a good idea. I was trying to use the `screen` parameter but it created issues when writing to the screen from a different thread. How solves`Array.Copy` this thread ownership problem? Why does this work and not a static parameter in my class (also using lock)?

Comment: Having a shared array **dedicated** to exchanging data means the only `Array.Copy` **which is fast** needs to be locked. This means that the threads are blocking each other less often and for shorter time.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `USBD480_DrawFullScreenBGRA32` is what actually writes to the LCD, and the rest of the code just prepares the image. I think your key to better performance is preparing the next image *while* the previous image is being written.

I think your best solution is to use two threads and use a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8) as a buffer for what needs to be written. One thread prepares the images and [puts them into the `ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.enqueue?view=netframework-4.8), and the other thread [pulls them off the queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.trydequeue?view=netframework-4.8) and writes them to the LCD. This way you don't have the overhead of calling `Task.Run` each time around.

It might also be wise to limit how many frames are written to the queue, so it doesn't get too far ahead and take up unnecessary memory.

Comment: I agree, that Task.Run is likely to be not needed.

Comment: @tymtam Yeah, now that I think about it more, I just removed the `Task.Run` code. The two threads really is the best way to do it.

Comment: How would you deal with a case when the producer is faster than the display-er? Wouldn't you grow and grow (and display old images)?

Comment: I'm presuming that each queue item will keep its copy of the image. At 60fps  this is not an insignificant number of allocations. What do you think?

Comment: That's the part I added at the end :) it is a good idea to limit the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the robust, performant, and highly configurable [TPL Dataflow library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), that will allow you to construct a pipeline of data. You will be posting raw data into the first block of the pipeline, and the data will be transformed while flowing from one block to the next, before being finally rendered at the last block. All blocks will be working in parallel. In the example bellow there are three blocks, all configured with the default `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`, so 3 threads at maximum will be concurrently busy doing work. I have configured the blocks with an intentionally small [`BoundedCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity), so that if the incoming raw data is more than what the pipeline can process, the excessive input will be dropped.

```
var block1 = new TransformBlock<Stream, BitmapFrame>(stream =>
{
    BitmapFrame bf = BitmapFrame.Create(stream);
    RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(bf, BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality);
    return bf;
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
{
    BoundedCapacity = 5
});

var block2 = new TransformBlock<BitmapFrame, int[]>(bf =>
{
    var pixels = new int[width * height * 4];
    bf.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), pixels, width * 4, 0);
    return pixels;
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
{
    BoundedCapacity = 5
});

var block3 = new ActionBlock<int[]>(pixels =>
{
    DisplayWrapper.USBD480_DrawFullScreenBGRA32(ref disp, pixels);
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
{
    BoundedCapacity = 5
});
```

The pipeline is created by linking the blocks together:

```
block1.LinkTo(block2, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
block2.LinkTo(block3, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
```

And finally the loop takes the form bellow:

```
void Loop()
{
    while (_IsRunning)
    {
        block1.Post(GetRawStreamData());
    }
    block1.Complete();
    block3.Completion.Wait(); // Optional, to wait for the last data to be processed
}
```

In this example 2 types of blocks are used, two [`TransformBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2)s and one [`ActionBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) at the end. The `ActionBlock`s do not produce any output, so they are frequently found at the end of TPL Dataflow pipelines.

An alternative to TPL Dataflow is a recently introduced library named [Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels?view=netcore-3.0), a small library that is easy to learn. This one includes the interesting option [`BoundedChannelFullMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.boundedchannelfullmode?view=netcore-3.0), for selecting what items are dropped when the queue is full:

> **DropNewest:** Removes and ignores the newest item in the channel in order to make room for the item being written.
>   **DropOldest:** Removes and ignores the oldest item in the channel in order to make room for the item being written.
>   **DropWrite:** Drops the item being written.
>   **Wait:** Waits for space to be available in order to complete the write operation.

In contrast TPL Dataflow has only two options. It can ether drop the item being written by using the demonstrated `block1.Post(...)`, or wait for space to be available by using the alternative `block1.SendAsync(...).Wait()`.

Channels are not a complete replacement of TPL Dataflow though, since they deal only with the queuing of the workitems, and not with their actual processing.

Comment: Hi Theodor, thank you very much for the elaborate explanation. How would this compare to a two-thread solution (memory/cpu wise)?

Comment: @Leon it will probably perform at least equally, and possibly better, to a manual thread-coding solution. It depends on how balanced the workload is. If for example the last step (the rendering) is the slowest one, then the performance will be equal, because both approaches will be limited by the same bottleneck, which is not parallelizable. If the second step is the slowest one, then with TPL Dataflow you have the option to increase the parallelism (`MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2`) of this block and get a better performance. I don't expect the improvement to be impressive though.

Comment: Memory-wise it depends on the `BoundedCapacity` setting. If for example you set it to 1 for all blocks, then at most 3 memory representations of a bitmap frame will be stored in the memory at the same time, one for each block. You can configure it, and it shouldn't be a problem, unless the memory resources of the system are extremely limited.

Comment: @Leon btw you should probably try to optimize the feeding loop. Currently you have a tight loop that totally consumes one CPU core, and possibly feeds the pipeline with the same raw data multiple times.

Comment: Yes I'm doing that in the real code. I'm using Thread.Sleep to limit the amount of cycles the feeding thread is going through. I have a small piece of code that tracks the amount of FPS that dynamically increases or decreases to keep as close to 60FPS as possible. I'm using that parameter to stay ahead of the consuming thread.

Comment: @Leon you are OK then. This small piece of code must be pretty smart! :-)