# Parallel tasks performance in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, task

I need to make Tasks run faster, I tried to use semaphore, parallel library and threads(tried to open one for every work, I know its the most dumb thing to do), but none of them show the performance I need. I'm not familiar to work with thread stuff and I need some help to find the right way and understand how Task and Threads work.

Here is the function:

```
 public class Test
    {
        public void openThreads()
        {
            int maxConcurrency = 500;
            var someWork = get_data_from_database();
            using (SemaphoreSlim concurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency))
            {
                List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var work in someWork)
                {
                    concurrencySemaphore.Wait();

                    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ScrapThings(work);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            concurrencySemaphore.Release();
                        }
                    });

                    tasks.Add(t);
                }

                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            }
        }

        public async Task ScrapThings(Object work)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
            var response = client.GetAsync(work.url).Result;
            var buffer = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            string content = utf8.GetString(buffer);
            /*
             Do some parse operations, load html document, get xpath, split things, etc 
             */

            while(true) // this loop runs from 1~15 times
            {
                response = client.GetAsync(work.anotherUrl).Result;
                buffer = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                content = utf8.GetString(buffer);
                if (content == "OK")
                    break;

                await Task.Delay(10000); //I need some throttle here before it tries again
            }
            /*
                Do some parse operations, load html document, get xpath, split things, etc 
                */
            update_things_in_database();
        }
    }
```

I want to make this task run 500 times in parallel, all the operation takes 18 hours to complete and I need to decrease this, I'm using xeon with 32 cores/64 threads. I tried to open 500 threads (better performance comparing to semaphore and parallel library) but it doesnt feel the right way to do.

Comment: Are you sure the performance is limited by CPU and not something else? With `ScrapThings` you've got `await Task.Delay(10000); //I need some throttle here before it tries again` - I'm assuming this is because you're avoiding spamming a server and being rate limited, but if you've got 500 tasks all going at the same time that delay isn't going to work and you'll be rate limited.

Comment: Why there is so much blocking calls like `client.GetAsync(work.url).Result` in `async` method?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I'm using .net 4.7.2.
I need to use `await Task.Delay(10000);`  because that operation take some time, I can only proceed if I get the message "OK", sometimes it shows "NOT_READY" message and I need to wait some time.

`client.GetAsync(work.url).Result` I can't proceed and to the next step if I don't have this result, after the result I need to do some parse things to extract and information I need before I do the next step.

Comment: Sounds like you need producer-consumer with set number of continuous threads

Comment: @BrunoLeyne but why not just to `await client.GetAsync(work.url)`?

Comment: @GuruStron Whats the difference to use await and client.GetAsync(work.url).Result ?

Comment: ".Result" blocks executing thread. But in your case I would say this is not an source of issues. Please see my answer.

Comment: 200 to 1 odds that it is _your_ code causing performance issues and you think Tasks/Threads/[pick your poison] is the cause since you never profiled the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say problem with performance is not with how you run your threads, but how individual threads are performing. Depended on version of .NET/libraries you are using there are few possible issues.

1. You should reuse `HttpClient` instances, for reasons explained [here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) for example.
2. If `work.url` and `work.anotherUrl` use the same subset of domains you should look into connection limit per endpoint (and total also). Depended on version either [HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=netcore-3.1) or [ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.connectionlimit?view=netcore-3.1) and [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=net-5.0) . The former one is for .NET Core and latter for [.NET Full framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/timomta/controlling-the-number-of-outgoing-connections-from-httpclient-net-core-or-full-framework).

The recommended approach to solve the first issue is to use [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

And some more [info](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/330379/365370).

**UPD**

You mentioned in comments that you are using .NET 4.7.2 so I would suggest to start with adding next lines to your application (somewhere at the start):

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 500;
// if you can get collection of most scrapped ones:
var domains = new [] { "http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk" };
foreach(var d in domains)
{
    var delayServicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(d));
    delayServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 10; // or bigger
}
```

Comment: I cant reuse HttpClient because of cookies/sessions management. I have 86 ScrapThings functions that are different because I need to scrap different things. I never used IHttpClientFactory, I'll read the documents to see whats the difference. I'll take some time to read.

Comment: 1) See the update 2) you can if you use factory or just pool of `HttpClient`'s.

Comment: Thank you for all the information, by now I'm reading all the docs you posted to understand how to manage http connections better and try the new aproaches. I need some time to process everything.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. You probably need different concurrency levels for the I/O bound operations (web requests, database updates) and the CPU-bound operations (parsing of the data). The TPL Dataflow allows to build a pipeline where each block is responsible for a single operation, and the data flows from one block to the next. It even allows for cyclic graphs, so for example you are allowed to throw a failed data element back into the block, so that it can be processed again.

For some examples of using this library, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213782/impact-of-using-asparallel-and-assequential-in-the-same-query-c-sharp/60236681#60236681), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456516/simple-parallelisation-for-hashset/61462269#61462269) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58402150/c-sharp-asynchronous-lcd-write/58404471#58404471).

The TPL Dataflow library is embedded in .NET Core, and available as a [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) for .NET Framework.