# I sent over than 100 requests to web service

Tags: c#, multithreading, web, parallel-processing, python-requests

I sent over than 100 requests to web service I am using `Parallel.Foreach` and it handle it well,  but when see the traffic using Wireshark I only see 4 or up to 10 requests per second.

Then I tried the same case on same machine in SOAPUI TOOL in bulk multi threading
Mode then I saw that the 100 requests are sent in same second.

Any advice nothing that I am using

- C# 2017
- Framework 4.5
- OS win 10
- CPU cores 4 I7
- RAM 16 GB

Comment: Any idea what should I do with this case

Comment: You are possibly hitting request number limits. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957315/parallel-tasks-performance-in-c-sharp/61957805#61957805) answer.

Comment: Do you own the web service?

Comment: The web service for our vendor "not in local  ",and did not limited the sent requests

Comment: @MohannadAsha Welcome to StackOverflow. The `Parallel.Foreach` was designed for CPU bound operations. That's why you see only a handful of requests, because you don't have 100 CPU cores :D Please prefer `Task.WhenAll` instead for I/O operations.

Comment: @MohannadAsha Please also share with us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to help you in more details.

Comment: You could try adding this line at the start of the program: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);`, and see if it makes any difference. If it does, it means that you are observing the effects of a saturated `ThreadPool`, and you need to change your methodology in order to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a parallel.foreach issue - the issue is ServicePointManager which throttles the number of parallel requests to any domain name. The standard is, as you found out, 4 parallel requests.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager?view=net-5.0

Parallel.ForEach will quue all the tasks, but then the requests run into the limitation. Oh, and that manager can be configured ;)